# Need help with category page customization meeting certain condition

Tags: categories, pages

I have 3 columns in my category page. On the left column, I want to show Recent posts only from that category I am viewing. In the middle column I want to show most viewed post only from that category and in the extreme right column I want o show all featured post.

I am unable to accomplish that, so needing help.

Comment: Could you show some code, what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

and read this article too:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Comment: I know how to show popular posts..and my question was not about how to show the popular posts but how to shows post from the category you are viewing. Anyway I hv fixed it by tweaking my query...The following code did the trick:

'<?php global $post; ?>
   <?php $categories = get_the_category(); foreach ($categories as $category) :?>
   <?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 20, 'category' => $category->term_id ); ?>
   <?php $myposts = get_posts( $args ); ?>
      
   <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?> '